# Sort NSMutableArray to an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to know if it's possible to sort an `NSMutableArray` while keeping it an **`NSMutableArray`** (not an `NSArray`).  Either creating a new sorted array or reusing the same array would be fine.

---------  edit -----------------

Thanks for all of your answers.

```
[unsortedList sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareStage:)];
```

sorting the unsortedList.

I had Confusion with sorted***Array***UsingSelector.

Comment: An NSMutableArray ***is*** an NSArray, it's a subclass

Comment: Yes but I need to do more transformation on the array after the sort. But it's impossible on NSArray, that's the reason why I would like to keep the NSMutableArray

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `NSMutableArray`? There are several methods for sorting the mutable array.

Comment: Use one of the NSMutableArray sortUsing... methods.  Using a NSArray sortedArray... method creates a new array, and I'm pretty sure it will always be non-mutable.

Comment: Not sure why folks are voting this question "unclear" -- it's perfectly clear.  The OP's main failing is in not first scanning the spec for NSMutableArray, since the answer was there.

Comment: Perfectly clear, this should be a 'minimal understanding' close but the majority rules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your original `NSMutableArray` itself using these methods...

```
- (void)sortUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))compare context:(void *)context;
- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator;
- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
- (void)sortWithOptions:(NSSortOptions)opts usingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
- (void)sortUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors;       // NSSortDescriptorSorting
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below piece of code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"someKey" ascending:YES];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[unsortedMutableArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: You could, of course, simply use `mutableCopy` vs `arrayWithArray`.

Comment: And you can use modern syntax to create the descriptors array: `@[ sortDescriptor ]`

Comment: Agreed. Updated my answer.